# How to find all "Featured examples" in the documentation?

Tags: documentation, example

How can I find all "Featured examples" in the documentation ? They are not neatly listed nor can they be simply searched using keywords.

I thought this had been asked before , but I cannot find the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to a "Featured Example" in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a list of the Featured Example notebook files included in the installed documentation, evaluate this (MMA 11.3, MMA 12):

```
fe = FileNames["*.nb", 
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
      "Documentation", "English", "System", "ExamplePages"}]];
Length[fe]

(*  631  *)
```

Then, to open one of the Featured Examples, evaluate

```
NotebookOpen[RandomChoice[fe]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I hoped there was a link somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: @LouisB is there an easy way to restrict this by version number? For example, to find the code for all these: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-12/